# How to get started with JHipster and microservices?

Tags: java, microservices, jhipster

I am using JHipster to not just make my company website, but the services we provide, from our store to learning zone, and then some at a later date. Now when I start just one microservice (learning) and my gateway, the gate way and learning will launch and be accessible from the browser, but JHipster will stop at 92% executing on the gateway. and 87% executing on the microservice. Consul will also show them as green.

Now I am slowly learning about microservices and building an app this way, and I am new to JHipster, but not Java.

Gateway setup

```
        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

                            https://www.jhipster.tech

Welcome to JHipster v7.6.0
Application files will be generated in folder: D:\SinLessGamesLLCWebsite\gateway
 _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

  Documentation for creating an application is at https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/
  If you find JHipster useful, consider sponsoring the project at https://opencollective.com/generator-jhipster
 _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

? Which *type* of application would you like to create? Gateway application
? What is the base name of your application? gateway
? As you are running in a microservice architecture, on which port would like your server to run? It should be unique to avoid port conflicts. 8080
? What is your default Java package name? com.sinlessgamesllc
? Which service discovery server do you want to use? Consul
? Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? JWT authentication (stateless, with a token)
? Which *type* of database would you like to use? SQL (H2, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB, Oracle, MSSQL)
? Which *production* database would you like to use? MySQL
? Which *development* database would you like to use? H2 with disk-based persistence
? Which cache do you want to use? (Spring cache abstraction) Hazelcast (distributed cache, for multiple nodes, supports rate-limiting for gateway applications)
? Do you want to use Hibernate 2nd level cache? Yes
? Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the backend? Gradle
? Which other technologies would you like to use? Apache Kafka as asynchronous messages broker, API first development using OpenAPI-generator
? Which *Framework* would you like to use for the client? React
? Do you want to generate the admin UI? Yes
? Would you like to use a Bootswatch theme (https://bootswatch.com/)? Darkly
? Choose a Bootswatch variant navbar theme (https://bootswatch.com/)? Dark
? Would you like to enable internationalization support? No
? Please choose the native language of the application English
     info Disabling hibernate cache for cache provider no
? Besides JUnit and Jest, which testing frameworks would you like to use? Cypress, [DEPRECATED] Protractor, Gatling, Cucumber
? Would you like to install other generators from the JHipster Marketplace? No
```

Learning setup

```
? Which *type* of application would you like to create? Microservice application
? What is the base name of your application? learning
? Do you want to make it reactive with Spring WebFlux? Yes
? As you are running in a microservice architecture, on which port would like your server to run? It should be unique to avoid port conflicts. 8089
? What is your default Java package name? com.sinlessgamesllc
? Which service discovery server do you want to use? Consul
? Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? JWT authentication (stateless, with a token)
? Which *type* of database would you like to use? SQL (H2, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB, MSSQL)
? Which *production* database would you like to use? MySQL
? Which *development* database would you like to use? H2 with disk-based persistence
? Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the backend? Gradle
? Which other technologies would you like to use? Apache Kafka as asynchronous messages broker, API first development using OpenAPI-generator
? Would you like to enable internationalization support? No
? Please choose the native language of the application English
? Besides JUnit and Jest, which testing frameworks would you like to use? Cypress, [DEPRECATED] Protractor, Gatling, Cucumber
? Would you like to install other generators from the JHipster Marketplace? No
```

My question is: did I mess something up? Am I going at this the wrong way?

I do great learning by myself and hands on, and I prefer to be productive as I learn to give myself a sense of accomplishment while achieving what I needed. So I would rather make my site right at first and be able to easily add and manage it than do it wrong and run into problems down the road.

### Update

Just a bit more info on my situation. So I left my PC on overnight just to see if the gateway and learning would hit 100% for executing. As of this point they have been running and accessible for 15h 51m so I have come to a conclusion it might just be a bug?

Also my computer has 52GB of ram and is running with a intel core i5-9400f @2.90GHz 6 cores with 6 threads.

Comment: Any reason why you want to go microservices first? For a web site and an API, a monolith would be much simpler and less expensive (especially Consul). Not sure what you mean by  92% and 87%, I suppose it's gradle build progress, which part? How much RAM do you have on your PC?

Comment: Gaël Marziou I have 52GB of Ram on my pc. And the reason why i want to go with a micro service archetecture, is It would be better for the long run, I have a start up game design  and software development company, and my website is the face and the store to my company i really want it to be easy to scale. I also plan to use it for a package manager and several other things in the future. so starting it out right i would assume is the best bet.